# Random Article button

Tags: html, c, apache, drupal, hash

I'd like to create a button on a menu bar that can generate a link to a random article from my blog posts (much like Wikipedia has). It's for a client, and they'd like to have this functionality on the site. I'm not familiar with PHP so I'd like to find a way around that, especially since I don't have access to the root user on my server host's mySQL installation (if this is relevant).

I had a theoretical solution: have a .txt or .xml file containing a list of all the URLs to each of the posts, with a "key" assigned to each of them. Then, when the user clicks the random article button, the current time (ex. 1:45) is hashed and mapped to a specific URL. I am fairly new to Drupal, however, I was wondering if there was some way to have the random article button use a .c file to execute these steps. The site is being hosted on a server that uses Apache 2, and I looked through some modules that were implemented in C code. I'm pretty new to all of this (although proficient in C), and spent many fruitless hours searching for solutions.

Comment: C is probably not the right tool for this job.

Comment: php then? not sure how long it would take me to learn it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a pure Drupal fashion (don't know if you are interested by this kind of solution), you could create a view (create a block) which retrieve blog posts, use a random sort criteria and limit results to 1 item. Then configure this view to display fields, and add only one field : post title, and check "link to content" in this field parameters window. You'll get one random blog post title which will be rendered as a link to this blog post.

Finally in Structure->Block assign your new block in a region to see it.

It's a pure Drupal / Views / no-code-just-clicks :) way, but it will be far more maintainable and easy to setup than introducing C for such a simple feature.

[Views module](https://drupal.org/project/views)

Let me know if you try this and have problems configuring your view or anything else.

Good luck